# How to parse arrays with different levels PHP

Tags: php, arrays

In a foreach loop i would like to compare [name] value beetween different arrays but they have not the same levels.

```
Array(
    [array1] => Array
       (
           [0] => WP_Term Object
               (
                   [name] => Plafond
               )
       )

   [array2] => WP_Term Object
       (
           [name] => Chaudière
       )
   [array3] => Array
       (
           [0] => WP_Term Object
               (
                   [name] => Pla
               )
           [1] => WP_Term Object
               (
                   [name] => Toc
               )
       )
)
```

I don't know how could i get the [name] in the same loop whereas levels are different.
I have tried to make :

```
foreach( $fields as $name => $value )
  {
    echo   $value->name;  }
```

Should i add another loop in the first loop ?
thanks

Comment: Is that all ONE array with different sub arrays in it?

Comment: yes it it , and array2 is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your data looks like this:

```
$json = '{"array1":[{"name":"Plafond"}],"array2":{"name":"Chaudière"},"array3":[{"name":"Pla"},{"name":"Toc"}]}';
$array = json_decode($json);
```

If you don't know how deep it will go, a simple recursive function should work. Perhaps something like this:

```
function get_name($o, &$output) {
    if (is_array($o)) {
        foreach($o as $v) {
            get_name($v, $output);
        }
    } elseif (property_exists($o, "name")) {
        $output[] = $o->name;
    }
}

$output = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    get_name($v, $output);
}
```

If you data is going to look like the sample you provided (i.e. it will always be first or second level) then you don't need to worry about recursion.

```
$output = [];
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
    if (is_array($v)) {
        foreach ($v as $k2=>$v2) {
            $output[] = $v2->name;
        }
    } else {
        $output[] = $v->name;
    }
}
```

Either way, your output values are all in the `$output` array:

```
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Plafond
    [1] => Chaudière
    [2] => Pla
    [3] => Toc
)
```

Comment: better recursive answer, i neglected to notice the presence of those objects

Comment: i don't understand if i must use JSON. Actually , my array is returned in a variable $fields.

Comment: @pipoulito I used JSON to create a [mcve]. It’s just an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map`, `array_key_exists` to retrive the `name` index from the array

```
$jsonFormat = '{"array1":[{"name":"Plafond"}],"array2":{"name":"Chaudière"},"array3":[{"name":"Pla"},{"name":"Toc"}]}';
$jsonArray  = json_decode($jsonFormat,true);
$res = [];
array_map(function($v) use (&$res){
   if(array_key_exists('name', $v)){
     $res[] = $v['name'];
   }else{
     foreach($v as $_key => $_value){
        $res[] = $_value['name'];
     }
  }
}, $jsonArray);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```

Result:-

```
Array
(
 [0] => Plafond
 [1] => Chaudière
 [2] => Pla
 [3] => Toc
)
```

You can use `$res` to compare the names.